# Big commerce authorization ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, authorization, bigcommerce

I am working with Big Commerce API. We just use Big Commerce Hosted Shop and no extra hosing.
So we cannot use BC API in PHP code.

I try to call ajax to get some additional data such as custom fields to display separately.

My solution is to create an user with Permission "Manage Product". Then I use this credentials to create Ajax call.

Here is ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'https://store-convvXX.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/85/customfields.json',
dataType: 'json',
//'otherSettings': 'othervalues',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    //May need to use "Authorization" instead
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
        "Basic amF2YXNjcmlwdF91c2VyOjI0MmEwMTU1NWYyYjk4OTk1MzI3MmM1MDQxYjU1MTlj");
},
success: function(result) {
    alert('done');
    document.write(result);
},
error: function(){
    alert('error');
}
```

});

However, I always get response 401. Anyone can share with me your experience.
I will appreciate any of your inputs so much.

Comment: did u try the url in the web browser??it says no such site...

Comment: Yes, I work in browser with a popup letting me enter username and password. After that, I get production json data. (I changed my site 43 to XX in URL:))

Comment: are you running the ajax code from an https supported site?

Comment: No, it is unencrypted page. :(. Is there any solution for that? Because I don't have a server side script either force every page to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to base64 encode the api key like it says in the [bigcommerce manual](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/legacy/basic-auth)

javascript uses btoa() function for base64 encoding.